# Magento core Classes

Tags: magento

I looked over the net and i couldn't find any elaboration on some magento core classes, can someone please explain to me the purpose of these magneto core classes.

Mage_core_Model_abstract

Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract

Mage_core_model_mysql4_collection _abstract

Mage_core_model_resource

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to understand

http://alanstorm.com/magento_listener_lifecycle_block

please check this once